# Issue with cache?

Tags: php, caching

I'm trying to install a webviewer for Teamspeak 3 (a VoIP program) but I do have some issues. First of all, the official website has discontinued support as of 1 month ago, so I cannot ask them unfortunately.

When I go to the webviewer page the first time everything seems to work just fine. However if I refresh the page it goes white and loads until I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Users\[...]\TSQuery.class.php on line 414
```

Here is line 414 from that file:

```
    $ret .= fgets($this->connection, 8096);
```

and the whole function:

```
private function send_raw($text)
{
    $i = -1;
    $ret = '';
    if ($this->connection === NULL)
    {
        $this->open_new_connection();
    }
    stream_set_timeout($this->connection, 0, 300000);
    fputs($this->connection, $text);

    do
    {
        $ret .= fgets($this->connection, 8096);
    }
    while (strstr($ret, "error id=") === false);

    return $ret;
}
```

I have tried this both on my webhost and moving the script over to the same server as the VoIP is installed on (thinking the host might be causing something) - but to no difference.

When I put the script as an iframe on my webhost and reload the page twice the whole site goes down!

```
Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
Apache Server at www.site.com Port 80
```

But back to my own server, every now and again (1 / 10 loads or so) I get:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: TSQuery::$cachepath in C:\Users\[...]\TSQuery.class.php on line 85
```

and here is line 85:

```
$this->cachepath .= $port . "/";
```

and the whole function:

```
public function use_by_port($port)
{
    if (is_numeric($port))
    {

        $resp = $this->send_cmd("use port=" . $port);
        if ($resp['error']['id'] === 0)
        {
            $this->cachepath .= $port . "/";
        }
        return $resp;
    }
    return false;
}
```

any ideas???

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you think it's a bad idea to start learning and working with a tool that is discontinued?

Comment: Not really, no. I've seen this tool on many websites and I know it should work. It was last updated May 3rd so it's not exactly outdated or old.

Answer (score 1):

```
do
{
    $ret .= fgets($this->connection, 8096);
}
while (strstr($ret, "error id=") === false);
```

The code above means: ***connect WHILE not first occurence of "error_id=" is found (is false).*** This means that if no errors occur it will connect in an infinite loop and I believe that's why you're getting a timeout.

**UPDATE:**

I would skip the do/while and do something like this instead:

```
if(!$this->connection) return false;

$output = fgets($this->connection, 8096);
fputs($this->connection, $text);
fclose($this->connection);

if (substr($output, 0, 4) == '1 OK') return true;

return false;
```

Comment: aha. I'm thinking convert the do-while into an if statement (keep same condition)? What do you think?

Comment: Okay what I suggested stopped the freezing, but it barely loads anything. Unless you have any suggestions, I guess I'll have to experiment with different solutions.

Comment: I think I would skip the do/while-part and check for the return value. Check my update.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I wasn't sure if you wanted me to replace the whole function or just the loop. Either way it seemed like I was getting one error: PHP Warning:  fgets(): 26 is not a valid stream resource - and the same error for fputs() and fclose().